# Putting external website with products inside my website

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1

I'm running Magento 1.9.

One of my suppliers has set up a system where you can have their products in a non branded website and use it yourself.  This would save hours putting products on and also when they update, we'd be automatically updated.    Is it possible to put the weblink they gave me somewhere so when I click a category on my homepage, it would open their site in where the sub categories and products would show whilst staying on my page?  You'd ideally have no idea that you were browsing another site as it would be within my site.  I imagine this would be bad for SEO though.

I know I've not explained that very well but hopefully you'll understand what I mean :)

Answer (score 0):

No, too complex, the best is to upload their products and provide an external link to their site - like an affilite site. You need to ghost the link with your own domain and then perform a server side redirect, otherwise you end up with Google issues.